# How to position a div to the bottom of the container?

Tags: html, css

I need to set `<div id="group-of-tables">` to the bottom of the `<div class="item-content">`, and **without using absolute position**.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="item-content">
    <div id="group-of-tables">
        <table class="item" id="first-table">
            <tr>
                <td><div class="" id="">1</div></td>
                <td><div class="" id="">2</div></td>
                <td><div class="" id="">3</div></td>
                <td><div class="" id="">4</div></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <table class="item" id="second-table" border="1">
            <tr>
                <td><div class="" id="">Next</div></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.item-content{
    height:100%;
}
```

Something like this:

[image]

Comment: I can't think of other way doing it than with absolute positioning. Is position: fixed; bottom: 0; also inconvinient (I suppose it is, since it sticks to the browser window)?

Comment: Maybe with `vertical-align: bottom;`. See a [demo here](https://jsfiddle.net/lmgonzalves/hyoxv5gj/).

Comment: Why do you not want to use `position: absolute`?

Comment: because absolute div will ignore another information from above

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do it with CSS `flex`, and don't forget to prefix all the flex related rules to make it to work more browsers, visit [this link](http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox) to see more support details, visit [this link](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) to learn more.

**[JsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/agcwur0h/)**

```css
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
}
.wrap {
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: flex-end;
}
.top {
    flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
    <div class="top">Top</div>
    <div class="bottom">Bottom</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Basically i need to attach div with id group-of-tables to the bottom of item-content

Comment: @RuslanLomov yes, I was trying to make the demo as simple as possible (and shows you if you also have content on the top), [this demo](http://jsfiddle.net/56y1hhhs/) is what you're asking for I think.

Comment: what if height of item-content sets in script after full page load. It is not 100 % from the start.

Comment: @RuslanLomov the 100% is just an example, you can set any height you want, try it first, and come back if you need more help.